# How to load JS file in run time in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to load different JS file in Angular for different environment because the prefix for my js file is different and I can't save them in my local.

in dev

```
js file path is http://myproject-dev.com/product.js
```

so my html will be like

```
 <script src="http://myproject-dev.com/product.js"></script>
```

prod

```
js file path is http://myproject.com/product.js
```

my html is like

```
<script src="http://myproject.com/product.js"></script>
```

I need to load them based on the environment, I have a variable set in JS to detect the environment but I don't know how to load them in html or in run time in Angular. Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relative URL.

Same position: `<script src="product.js"></script>`.

With a subfolder from current position: `<script src="scripts/product.js"></script>`

With a subfolder from root: `<script src="/scripts/product.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use relative paths to reference your files rather than using the full URL.

if you directory structure looks like this:

- js

  - product.js
- index.html

then inside of index.html you can reference product.js like this:

```
<script src="js/product.js"></script>
```